# sizeof operator error on data types

Tags: c

I found it strange, that I am getting compile error when using `sizeof int`, while `sizeof var` (where var is a variable) works just fine.

```
int a;

a = (int) sizeof( a ); //ok
a = (int) sizeof( int ); //ok

a = (int) sizeof a; //ok
a = (int) sizeof int; //error
```

Can anyone tell me, why do I get the error?

(older machine, mac osx 10.5.8, gcc 4.0.1)

Comment: You can read the MSDN documentation that explains it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w557fh7.aspx

Comment: @AurA how about a link to the relevant C and/or C++ specs instead of a Microsoft compiler's docs?

Comment: @Alnitak A non Microsoft doc http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the C standard (cited from ISO/IEC 9899:TC3 section 6.5.3.4):

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.

So using a type name without parenthesis isn't legal.

Also, `sizeof` returns an implementation defined value of the type `size_t` and you probably should not cast it.

Answer (score 3):

A parenthesis is required when the operand of the `sizeof` operator is a type name (`int`, `float`, `char`....).

Answer (score 2):

### **sizeof Syntax**

```
sizeof( type )  //need parenthesis for data type eg. int, float

sizeof  expression //No parenthesis for variable or expression
```